# Having Trouble Figuring this code out with if else statements for radio buttons

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am having trouble with this

[image]

please click that for the instructions.Image did not load in for some reason.

This is my current code, honestly I am confused and dont really know how to approach this. I am new to javascript and was trying to do this as practice for an upcoming exam. I really hope someone can help me figure this out. I know the javascript is not finished and what I currently have is probably wrong but I am just confused on where to take this. Thanks

```js
  Function tips() {
                var mealCost=parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtMealCost").value);
                var Great1= document.getElementById("great");
                var Okay2= document.getElementById("okay");
                var Poor3= document.getElementById("poor");
                var totalCost1= mealCost * .20
                if (document.getElementById("great").checked) {
                    
                
                    
                    
                    
                }
            }
```

```html
  
        <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
        <hr>
        <span>What was the cost of your meal? </span>
        <input type="text" id="txtMealCost" />
        <hr>
        How would you rate the service?<br>
        Great (20%) <input type="radio" name="radServiceQuality" id="great"> <br>
        Okay (15%) <input type="radio" name="radServiceQuality" id="okay"> <br>
        Poor (10%) <input type="radio" name="radServiceQuality" id="poor"> <br>
    
        <p><input type="button" value="Calculate Tip Amount" onclick="calcTip()">
    
            <div id="output">
            </div>
```

Comment: What is problem in code. What you can't understand please mention that

Comment: I am confused on how to approach this how do I assign the radio buttons a percentage value? How do I write if else statements that calculate the cost of the tip after they click a radio button depending on what percentage they clicked on.

Comment: why won't you put your homework question in the question as text? - https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/20-overall-grade-consider-web-page-wish-create-simple-tip-calculator-page-asks-user-cost-m-q33068825

Comment: for a start, in javascript it is `function` not `Function` - and clearly the function should be `calcTip` not `tips` - as is spelled out in the HTML portion of the question (as per above link)

Comment: @JaromandaX hey did u just post that on chegg or was that already there? Also yea I am doing this as practice cause I have an exam later so i was trying to understand this code. Thank you for linking me to the chegg. Also I just fixed the function thing and added a value. I am approaching this in a different way I will post the current code can you tell me if this is accurate as well?

Comment: Yes, I posted on that Chegg, and changed the H1 to `Common Question, Fall 2018` to mess with you

Comment: the main issue with the amount of the question you posted is ... you'll probably get answers that use more logical HTML than whatever dumbass wrote the question :p so the code won't help if the HTML in the answers is different to the required HTML in the dumbass question :p

Comment: @JaromandaX new codenotcheg
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function tips() {
            var mealCost=parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtMealCost").value);
            var Great1= document.getElementById("great");
            var Okay2= document.getElementById("okay");
            var Poor3= document.getElementById("poor");
            var totalCost1= mealCost * .20
            if (document.getElementById("great").checked) {
                
            alert(totalCost1);
                
                
                
            }
        }

    </script>

Comment: right - not sure why you posted that in a comment directed at me

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```js
// es6 style function, same as "function(){...}"
tips = () => {
  // Getthe selected radio 
  let selected = document.querySelector(`input[name='radServiceQuality']:checked`);
  // If a radio is selected 
  if (selected) {
    // Cast as number
    var mealCost = +document.getElementById("txtMealCost").value;
    // Format the number as curency
    let totalCost = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD'
    }).format(selected.value * mealCost);
    // Set output string
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = totalCost;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>IT-130 Exam</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
  <hr>
  <span>What was the cost of your meal? </span>
  <input type="text" id="txtMealCost" />
  <hr> How would you rate the service?
  <br> Great (20%) <input type="radio" id='great' name="radServiceQuality" value=".2">
  <br> Okay (15%) <input type="radio" id='okay' name="radServiceQuality" value=".15">
  <br> Poor (10%) <input type="radio" id='poor' name="radServiceQuality" value=".1"> <br>

  <p><input type="button" value="Calculate Tip Amount" onclick="tips()">

    <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

IFF the HTML is not allowed to be changed, this shall do the trick:

```js
// Helper function to determine percent to apply
getPercent = selectedId => {
  switch (selectedId) {
    case 'great':
      return .2;
    case 'okay':
      return .15;
    case 'poor':
      return .1;
  }
};

// es6 style function, same as "function(){...}"
calcTip = () => {
  // Getthe selected radio 
  let selected = document.querySelector(`input[name='radServiceQuality']:checked`);
  // If a radio is selected 
  if (selected) {
    // set percent
    let percent = getPercent(selected.id);
    // Cast as number
    var mealCost = +document.getElementById("txtMealCost").value;
    // Format the number as curency
    let totalCost = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD'
    }).format(percent * mealCost);
    // Set output string
    document.getElementById('output').innerText = totalCost;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>IT-130 Exam</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
  <hr>
  <span>What was the cost of your meal? </span>
  <input type="text" id="txtMealCost" />
  <hr> How would you rate the service?<br> Great (20%) <input type="radio" name="radServiceQuality" id="great"> <br> Okay (15%) <input type="radio" name="radServiceQuality" id="okay"> <br> Poor (10%) <input type="radio" name="radServiceQuality" id="poor">  <br>

  <p><input type="button" value="Calculate Tip Amount" onclick="calcTip()">

    <div id="output">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: you can avoid `/ 100` by setting values to `.2` etc - though, if you look at the WHOLE question (link in one of my comments in the question) - while I agree your code is **the** way to do it, the question asks for code only, no changes to HTML :p

Comment: @JaromandaX fair point, i've added an updated section that does not modify the markup

Answer (score 0):

The requirement provided is not clear enough.
Assuming you just need a simple output, what you should do in the function call is,

1.find the value of the selected radio button

```
document.querySelector('input[name="radServiceQuality"]:checked').value
```

2a. Decide the tip ratio

```
if (selected_value = 'great') tip_percentage = 0.2;
```

2b. Calculate the tip

```
tip = meal_cost * tip_percentage;
```

3.output the tip

```
alert(tip);
```

You should go through some javascript basic tutorial. And keep on googling.